# kendo angular chart does not draw when array is pushed to the datasource

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I can see my array in the console when i log it,but it does not draw the chart here is the chart:

```
  <kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-title text="Units sold"></kendo-chart-title>
  <kendo-chart-series>    
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="line" [data]="seriesData">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

here is component:

```
 public seriesData: number[][]=[] ;
  public x:number[][]=[];
```

the following works and draws a chart:

```
this. seriesData = [
    [16.4, 7], [21.7, 9], [25.4, 5], [19, 2]
];
```

but the following does not work:

```
  this.x=[
  [5,4],[3,6]
      ]
      this. seriesData.push(this.x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-chart-bkdfzs) use this

```
this. seriesData = [ [16.4, 7], [21.7, 9], [25.4, 5], [19, 2] ];
this.x=[[5,4],[3,6] ];
this. seriesData=this. seriesData.concat(this.x);
```

Comment: perfectly worked thanks!can you tell me why push did not work?

Comment: You're welcome :) Because x is also same type with seriesData. U can push inside x not directly x. But concat two series is better way to inside x with loop